# воспроизвести звук

Tags: java

У меня есть цикл while, в нем каждую секунду отправляется запрос в api, мне нужно, чтобы если значение например "true", то программа издает звук, также как и "false", но надо чтобы этот звук воспроизводился 1 раз, то есть если значение тру и след тоже тру, то звука не должно быть

Answer (score 1):

Логическая схема приблизительно такая:

```
private boolean sound = false;

public void apiCaller() {
   //blah-blah
   sound = false;
   while(something) {
       boolean result = callApi();  //вызываем API
       if (result && !sound)  //если результат вызова API true и  звук еще не проигрывался
          playSound();
    }
}

private void playSound() {
   sound=true;
   //blah-blah
}
```

Сама реализация собственно проигрывания звука/писка - зависит от платформы: консоль, JavaFX или Android